# How to transform an integer value sparse matrix to 0/1 value sparse matrix, Python

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix from the sklearn bag-of-words vectorizer. It's a csr_matrix and its elements represent word frequency in a document. But now what I need is the 0/1 matrix where 1 represents the word exists in the document, so I don't care about the actual frequency. 
Disregard the background problem, it's like this:
I have a sparse matrix,

```
2 3 4 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 8
0 0 0 2 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I want all the nonzero elements to be 1,

```
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How can I achieve this? I assume using todense() and then loop is not a good choice since the sparse matrix is large. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [csr_matrix.sign](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.sign.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.sign). it should be exactly what you need (although I didn't try it myself).

Answer (score 1):

I think you could just create a new matrix from the non-zero indices (see the [scipy.sparse.csr_matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix) reference). Assuming your sparse matrix is named sp_m:

```
sp_unit = csr_matrix( ([1]*len(sp_m.data), sp_m.nonzero()), shape=sp_m.shape )
```

**OR**

As another user pointed out, you could use the sign function; however, I think you will need to square it if you have negative values:

```
sp_unit = sp_m.sign.multiply(sp_m.sign)
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! .sign() seems have solved my problem

Comment: Just be aware that if you have negative values in your sparse matrix those will be converted to -1 after using .sign(). If you really want just 0's and 1's in the general case use the .sign in conjunction with .multiply as above.